# How to install local python packages when building jobs under Github Actions?

Tags: python, github, pip, github-actions, requirements.txt

I am building a python project -- `potion`. I want to use Github actions to automate some linting & testing before merging a new branch to master.

To do that, I am using a slight modification of a Github recommended python actions starter workflow -- [Python Application](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/82c43562976aef3d8f02643e00e979d65993244c/ci/python-app.yml).

During the step of "Install dependencies" within the job, I am getting an error. This is because pip is trying to install my local package `potion` and failing.

The code that is failing `if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi`

The corresponding error is:

```
ERROR: git+https@github.com:<github_username>/potion.git@82210990ac6190306ab1183d5e5b9962545f7714#egg=potion is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Most likely, the job is not able install the package `potion` because it is not able to find it. I installed it on my own computer using `pip install -e .` and later used `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create the requirements file.

Since I use this package for testing therefore I need to install this package so that pytest can run its tests properly.

**How can I install a local package (which is under active development) on Github Actions?**

Here is part of the [Github workflow file](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/82c43562976aef3d8f02643e00e979d65993244c/ci/python-app.yml) `python-app.yml`

```
...
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
...
```

Note 1: I have already tried changing from `git+git@github.com:<github_username>...` to `git_git@github.com/<github_username>...`. Pay attention to `/` instead of `:`.

Note 2: I have also tried using other protocols such as `git+https`, `git+ssh`, etc.

Note 3: I have also tried to remove the alphanumeric `@8221...` after git url `...potion.git`

Comment: Could you include the `potion` entry from your requirements.txt file in your post?

Comment: `-e git+git@github.com:<github_username>/potion.git@a3edd62c15257dc0e3755558ab1faa573bf0cd3d#egg=potion` -> that's what potion looks like in requirements.txt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "package under test", `potion` in your case, should not be part of the requirements.txt. Instead, simply add your line

```
pip install -e .
```

after the line with `pip install -r requirements.txt` in it. That installs the already checked out package in development mode and makes it available locally for an `import`.

Alternatively, you could put that line at the latest needed point, i.e. right before you run `pytest`.